# What does 'turn on' mean exactly in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The dialogue is about a mole who would provide them secret information about the inner circle.

> – I don't buy it. Didn't you tell me yourself, nobody **turns on
>   al-Qaeda?**
>
> – The Jordans have worked him for a year, dinners, money. They
>   convinced him... it's his patriotic duty to **turn on al-Qaeda**, and 
>   get rich doing it.

(Film: Zero Dark Thirty - United States, 2012)

Comment: Related term: [turncoat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turncoat)

Comment: Aside - I suspect it's 'dinars', not dinners!

Comment: Nobody who is supporting al-Quaeda will start working against them (probably because it is not good for your health).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I haven't seen the film, but from the context I can guess that it means "to betray". "To turn on someone" means "to betray (someone)": "He turned on me" means "He betrayed me" (he was "with" me and now he is "against" me, and thus he "turned" on me).

(Note that this should not be confused with "to turn someone on" which means "to arouse"...)

Comment: worth noting the difference in spoken inflection.  To betray someone is to _**turn** on them._  To sexually arouse someone is to _turn **on** that person  (_ or _turn them **on**_)

Comment: *Turn on X* can also mean *to move a switch controlling the power of X to on position* as well, e.g. *I turned on the lights.*

Comment: @LawrenceC I'd quibble that it doesn't necessarily mean flipping a physical switch. We often say things like, "If the sensor detects that the temperature has increased more than 2 degrees, it turns on the cooling system", etc. That is, you can turn something on electronically, with software, etc.

Comment: And the switch-flipping meaning can have either inflection. I think most often you say **turn** on the lights, but you can turn **on** the lights when you want to emphasize on versus off. In contrast, betrayal _always_ emphasizes **turn** and arousal _always_ emphasizes **on.**

Comment: @Adam: Word order matters too, probably moreso. I would have to think twice about it to interpret "to turn on that person" as "to arouse", whereas "to turn that person on" is clear.

Comment: *She turned on me after she turned me on*

Comment: My turn on this comment thread ;-)